# How can I get Notepad++ to correctly print to legal size paper?

Tags: windows, printing, notepad++

I cannot seem to get Notepad++ to correctly print to legal size paper.  I do not see any paper size options in the configuration settings, but when I change to a larger paper size in the print dialog, Notepad++ does not seem to pick it on and only prints a letter-size "window" set inside the larger page.

How can I get notepad++ to utilize all of the space of the larger paper size?

For example, here is a scan of what I'm seeing in my printouts (I added boarders in paint to make the paper size clearer):

[image: messed up printout]

I am using version 6.9.2.

Here are my Notepad++ print settings:

[image: notepad++ print settings]

Here are my printer settings from the print dialog:

[image: printer settings from print dialog]

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that unfortunately Notepad++ is at the mercy of the printer driver in this case. It would be helpful to post a screenshot of the advanced tab.

Another work around may be print to Legal PDF then print the PDF, however that's clearly a work around not a fix.

Comment: Notepad++ is the only program that seems to have this problem.  All of the other programs I've tried can print correctly to legal size paper.

Answer (score 0):

When you select the page size, the one circled in the last image, hit "other size..."
in there will bring up a dialog to select sizes. You want to change the option of "Original document size" to what you which it to be.

[Other Size Dialog Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOKDU.png)

Figured this out because I use notepad++ for note taking (among other things), and use sliced up letter paper 4.2" x 5.5" size. Just remember, if you want to set it as the default for notepad++ go into saved settings and have it save as the program's default.

Comment: And yes, this oddly only happens with notepad++...